# @material-ui/pickers is installed "successfully", but when starting the dev server it "Fails to compile"

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

In the process of creating a simple react.js app I decided I wanted to create a DatePicker to be displayed within a SimpleForm.

To do this I've tried installing the "npm i @material-ui/pickers" package and when that didn't work I installed the "npm i @material-ui-pickers" both didn't work, because after saving the project and starting the dev environment with "npm run dev" in the terminal (currently using VSCode on Windows)...I get the error:

- Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys' (here's a screenshot -->) [material-ui error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ0go.jpg)
- This is how my code looks like with the
  import { DatePicker, InlineDatePicker } from "material-ui/pickers"; (here's a snippet of the code)

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Create, SimpleForm, TextInput} from 'react-admin'
import { DatePicker, InlineDatePicker } from "material-ui/pickers";

const PlayListCreate = (props) => {
    return (
        <Create song_title='Create a playList' {...props}>
            <SimpleForm>
                <TextInput source='song_title' />
                <TextInput multiline source='body' />
                <DatePicker
                views={["year"]}
                label="Year only"
                value={selectedDate}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                animateYearScrolling
              />
            </SimpleForm>
            </Create>  
  )
}

export default PlayListCreate
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Your import path is wrong. The package is `@material-ui/pickers`, you're missing the "@" in your import statement

Comment: @Jayce444 Solution! Thanks!